# Dockerfile, groupadd with GUI parameter

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to add group with id declared in dockerfile, however I always get error:

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1001
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.1
ARG UID=1001
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server sudo
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:pycharm' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
RUN groupadd -r charm -g 1001
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash charm -g charm -u 1001
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
ADD helpers /opt/.pycharm_helpers
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Error message I get when I try to enter container with:

```
docker exec -ti -u 1001 pydebug1 bash
```

Group doesn't exists in `/etc/group` file. When I run commands inside container then works but I want to have them inside Dockerfile.

Comment: Have you tried running something like `docker run -it -u 1001 <container-name> /bin/bash -c 'grep 1001 /etc/group'` ?. It seems your problem is unrelated to info you provided

Comment: I've tried it in mac, built image by touching local file 'helpers'. Built image successfully and I can enter into the image without any issues. Please re-try.

Comment: @agg3l there is no group with that id when I do your command

Comment: @RobertRanjan did you enter the container successfully with `docker exec -ti -u 1001 pydebug1 bash` command?

Comment: Yes except the image name. I used the commit hash of image I built. What command did you use to built? did you see any error messages while you build it?

Comment: wait.. I see you used `exec` command. It won't work that if the container is not running already. You may see the right command in my answer.

Comment: Running `sshd` in a container is not needed as you can `exec` into a running container. You can have it if you really want to ssh into it.

Answer (score 0):

Saved your dockerfile content in Dockerfile and touched a file with name `helpers`.

Then build the image and enter into the image. Screen shot shows 2nd build, commit hash etc and `id` from the image. You can see all the commands in screen shot.

[image]

You may build as `docker build -t pydebug1 .` as well.